# Does the function has to be necessarily monotonically decreasing to apply Cauchy's Condensation Test?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Test the convergence of $$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{\log n}{n}\right)^2$$My textbook has used Cauchy's Condensation Test (CCT) to prove that the series is convergent. But I know that to apply CCT, the function $f(n)$ has to be monotonically decreasing. $\left(\frac{\log n}{n}\right)^2$ is not a monotonically decreasing function. Is my textbook wrong here?

[image]

Comment: First few terms do not matter for convergence and the terms here are decreasing after some stage. [From the third term on, to be specific].

Comment: @geetha290krm Okay, understood.

Comment: as a side note in this precise case you don't need CCT, just compare $(\log n)^2=o(\sqrt{n})$ and $\sum\frac 1{n^{3/2}}$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can create a similar function:

$$S' = \sum_{n=1}^\infty g(n)$$

Where $g(n) = \left(\frac{\log{n}}{n} \right) + a_n$

And choose a suitable $a_n$ that makes $g(n)$ non-increasing while having $a_n = 0 \ \forall n > 3$. Applying CCT on $S'$ yields that it is a convergent series, so you can then substract $\sum_{n=1}^3 a_n$ to it and check that your initial sum also converges.

Note that this would only work for the case when a finite number of initial terms of the sum are increasing.

Comment: This seems extremely convoluted in comparison to $\sum\limits_{n=n_0}^\infty f(n)$ starting from the adhoc $n_0$ after which $f$ is decreasing.

Comment: @zwim It is, not gonna lie, but the original form of CCT starts at $n=1$, and I think this was one of the main causes of the question being posted here